# I am getting error while setting decoded value to variable ? Is there any alternative for this?

Tags: php

I am creating `change username function` in that, I am unable to set decoded value to variable in php

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $fullname=$_GET["Fullname"];
    $uid=$_GET["uid"];
    $uid=str_replace("@","",$uid);
    $uid=str_replace(".","",$uid);
    $filename="data/".$uid.".html";
    $data=file_get_contents($filename);
    $data= rtrim($data, "\0");
    $json_parse=json_decode(trim(stripslashes($data)),True);
    $obj=$json_parse[0];
    $obj->Fullname=$fullname;
    $saveddata=json_encode($obj);
    file_put_contents($filename,$saveddata);
    echo $saveddata;
    //echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Assigning variables to variables is just a memory waste... You can debug you code by putting some [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) calls in your code and check the output of that.

Comment: We cannot say mich without you posting the information you actually have. Namely the _exact_ error message along with the _exact_ line where it occurs.

Comment: A wild guess: the `stripslashes()` probably invalidates the json string so that it cannot be decoded any more.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart I am getting internal server error 500    There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: @aishwaryak Check your PHP error log also for more details.

Comment: @arkascha  I used it bcz i was gtting internal server error so that I can remove if any backslashes and assign variable but still i am getting error

Comment: @ Scriptman how to use it sir?

Comment: @ mi6crazyheart how to check error log in php?

Comment: Your http server writes log files, one of them is the error log file. That is the first location you look at if you get an error. _Always_. So you have to find out where those log files are located. That is configured in your http servers configuration.

Comment: @ arkascha   I am not getting it where to see it ?